# Accessing Contents of "System.Reflection.Pointer"? (Python 3.10)

Tags: python, pointers, python.net

I'm calling a set of C# functions from a Python 3.10 script via the `clr` module from the `PythonNet` library. One of those functions returns a pointer of type `System.Reflection.Pointer`, that points to an array of `float` values.

I'm quite a bit confused as to how I'm exactly supposed to acquire or access the actual `float` array that the `System.Reflection.Pointer` variable is supposedly pointing to.

In my Visual Studio 2022 IDE, I can see that the pointer variable has a few class functions, such as `ToString()` or `Unbox()`, however none of those give me the desired `float` array.

What is the proper way of accessing the data pointed to by a `System.Reflection.Pointer` variable in Python?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with only Python.NET APIs. Create a C# converter(as a [class library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/class-libraries) and call it in Python, like the following example.

In C#, do like this.

```
using System.Reflection;

namespace Example;
public class Converter
{
    public static unsafe IntPtr PointerToIntPtr(Pointer p)
    {
        return (IntPtr)Pointer.Unbox(p);
    }
}
```

In Python, do like this.

```
import clr

clr.AddReference('path to the .NET dll')
import Example
...
# The ptr is assumed to be an instance of System.Reflection.Pointer
addr = Example.Converter.PointerToIntPtr(ptr).ToInt64()
# The addr will be an int.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to access or edit anything on the C# side here. I'm interfacing with some software, that was pre-packaged. I saw some other users talk about a `Marshal` class in C#, and it's class function `Copy`, however I have no idea how to use it. Would that be closer to what I need?

Comment: You don't need to modify existing C# modules. You need to create a new [class library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/class-libraries). It's very easy but you have to learn for a few hours if you don't have experience with C# and .NET.